# GridViewRowPresenter mouse hover trigger style override

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently working on an application that uses a GridView inside a ListView control.

I'm trying to change the blue hover/click effect on the selected row and so far I haven't been able to do it whatever I tried (and I tried a lot of things)

Related xaml from app.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewRowPresenter}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" /> <!-- This actually works here, but I can't change background -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Xaml listview code:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Foreground="#BDBDBD" Background="#090909" Name="Results">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="130"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="220"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Details}" Width="120"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I would really like to learn how to change that hover color in the gridview's template.. and I've looked everywhere, but no luck.. PS. I'm on windows 7, but same thing is on windows 8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why your first approach doesn't work (it must, which property you were setting?), but anyway here is a working one

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

You may want to deal with with `IsSelected` to distinguish selected and not selected highlight color. Then you may want to use `MultiDataTrigger`, e.g. below example remove highlight (only border still) for anything but selected item:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                   Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                   Value="False" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: This sort of worked. the highlight color still has a gradient for some reason.